# Textview , Button and ListView in one layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout which contains TextView , Button and ListView here is the following example

[image: example]

- Red box contains TextView
- Green box contains button
- Blue box contains **costumed ListView**

I have created a ListView activity now i don't know how to embed it with TextView and Buttons above

**Note** my ListView inflate the custom layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do my `extend Activity` also
on you can identify your controls like this

```
 setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);  
 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
 Button button= (Button ) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
 ListView listView = (ListView ) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
```

and you can set listView adapter like this

```
listView.setAdapter(CustomAdapeterClassObject)
```

Comment: Well i am using custom listview and inflate the layout so in that case what should i do ?

Comment: How you using `custom listview and inflate that layout`, I think your are doing by CustomAdapter

Comment: Ya i got it i passed that custom adapter , thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You'll use a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... />
    <Button  android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... />
    <ListView android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want your `ListView` to stretch to fill the remaining room on the screen, you use the `android:layout_weight` attribute as above.

Comment: Well i am extending ListActivity and inflate the custom layout (as i am showing icon and a textview ) , so how and where can i use <ListView> tag ?